# Redirect one URL to Another without creating a site

Tags: 2010, redirect

Lets say for example I have a URL that users are being directed to that has no actual content that exists there but I know what the URL would be.

I would like for this URL to be sent automatically to another URL of my choosing, is there a way to do this **without actually creating content in the initial URL**?

For example I know a user will hit the url:

```
http://mysite.com/spsite/spwebA
```

but I want them to be sent to

```
http://mysite.com/spsite/spwebB
```

I would like to avoid doing this using the [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) extension if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Put a content editor on the page of :

```
http://mysite.com/spsite/spwebA
```

Add below script in content editor webpart , as soon as user lands on spWebA ,it will redirect to spwebB :

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=http://mysite.com/spsite/spwebB">
```

If the page is start pWelcome Page [Home Page] of your SharePoint site, you have this option in Site Settings -> Under Look and Feel -> Welcome Page,

And here you can provide the URL of your Welcome Page to spwebb

Comment: This is by far the fastest and easiest way to do it. You should mention that you can change the second counter from 10 to 0 or 1 for an instant redirect. :)

Answer (score 0):

Web application extensions sounds like the solution for you. Navigate to the Central Administration, Manage Web Applications and select the web application you wish to use (Which I am assuming is 'SiteB'). In the ribbon there should be an "Extend" link. Fill in all the relevant details, including a new port number. At the bottom of the form you will see a field called "public URL", enter

> "http://mysite.com/subsite/siteA"

This will mean that no content actually sits on site A. This is assuming your content is already accessible by SiteB.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I don't know that this will work, these are both spwebs within the same spsite... I updated my question to give a better example.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before, but in my case I created a new subsite using the blank site template. This way the new site has nothing but a front page. Then I make that front page redirect to whatever URL I want.

Not sure if that will meet your requirements, but the user experience is what you described - they go to siteA and are magically whisked off to siteB instead.

For better answers, you may want to add the following detail to your question:

- Do you care what the actual URL at the top of the screen says after the redirect?
- Is there a specific need to NOT have content (even a single page) on siteA?
- Is siteA/siteB a site collection? Or just a subsite?